# getgsmsignalstrength giving me 99 in Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: android

I tried to track GSM signal strength with "getGsmSignalStrength" in galaxy S2. But it keeps giving value 99. Even when the phone got signal 4 bar it said 99.

Here is my code

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener  {

static SignalStrength mSignalStrength;
static int signal;

public static void signal() 
{

    signal = mSignalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();        
}
}
```

---

Then I called it from another class,

```
         signal2 = MyPhoneStateListener.signal;

       if (signal2 <= 2 || signal2 == 99) strength="No signal";
       else if (signal2 >= 12) strength="Very strong";
        else if (signal2 >= 8) strength="Strong";
        else if (signal2 >= 5) strength="Weak";
        else strength="Very weak";
```

It always say "No signal" even though I was watching out the signal bar and it showed two or three bars.

Does anyone know why it keep giving me that value or how to solve it ? I would be really appreciated for your answers or respond.

Comment: How do you know it is 99 and not 0? Do you get other values on another device?

Comment: It shows "no signal" even when it got good signal like 3 bar or 4 bar. That's why I thought it giving me 99 (That's my thought.It might be wrong).. I have only tried on Galaxy S2.

Comment: According to your if statement it could also be <=2. Since an field is initialized with 0 this could indicate that you never call the `signal()` method and the `signal` field does not get a value.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize mSignalStrength as below code :

```
mSignalStrength = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS
```